# Reconnect to screen and preserve splits

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

Is it possible to reconnect to a disconnected screen session and preserve the screen splits?

Comment: I don't know about screen, but it sure is possible with `tmux` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested screen sessions as a hack: http://aperiodic.net/screen/faq#when_i_split_the_display_and_then_detach_screen_forgets_the_split